# Getting label quadrant using PyQGIS?

Tags: labeling, pyqgis-3

How can I get the specified quadrant of a label using PyQGIS?

The print statements below return 1 and 0 no matter which option I pick in the dialog.

```
palyr = labeling.settings()
print(palyr.placement)
print(palyr.QuadrantPosition())
```

[image: quad]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the quadrant position by using [QgsPalLayerSettings::quadOffset()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a3382975c79e65dff517b0fd4854ed6b2):

```
layer.labeling().settings().quadOffset
```

This returns an enum integer reflecting the [QuadrantPosition](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a893793dc9760fd026d22e9d83f96c109) (e.g. 0 = `QuadrantAboveLeft`, 1 = `QuadrantAbove` etc.). We can create a dictionary to contain these values and then get the quadrant position name using something like:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

quads = {
        0: 'QuadrantAboveLeft',
        1: 'QuadrantAbove',
        2: 'QuadrantAboveRight',
        3: 'QuadrantLeft',
        4: 'QuadrantOver',
        5: 'QuadrantRight',
        6: 'QuadrantBelowLeft',
        7: 'QuadrantBelow',
        8: 'QuadrantBelowRight'
        }

quads[layer.labeling().settings().quadOffset]
>>> 'QuadrantAboveRight'
```